# Share Point 2013 My Site Global Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have branded Newsfeed and My Sites in Share Point 2013.

But the only thing that is missing is the Global Navigation on the My Sites and Newsfeed site. I have looked at site settings > Navigation and added Heading and links in Structural Navigation but no global navigation shows up.

Please show me how can I enable Global Navigation in My Sites and Newsfeed in on site Share Point 2013 My Sites.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  I'm in the same situation as you - I require it there for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You get to your `My Site` by clicking on `About Me`. While on your My Site, click on the `Sites` link at top right. There you should have a list of sites which you have visited or followed. You can click on any of those links and move away from the My Site.

So, there doesn't actually seems to be a need of any other Global Navigation. I don't know if you have some specific use-case for this.

Let us know if it helped.

Comment: The need for Global Navigation is not a functional one. It is more for aesthetics reasons. We have our sharepoint site that has global navigation and it should be replicated through out My sites so the users don't feel they are on another site.